# WSO2 2.6.0 Api Store console not rendering example/model on Internet Explorer browser 11

Tags: internet-explorer-11, wso2-api-manager, wso2, wso2-esb

I am using WSO2 Api manager 2.6.0 for Api creation.
With swagger 2.0, API had been created successfully.
Unfortunately client has escalated that store console is not rendering API example/model on Internet explorer but chrome and Mozilla.
Client is explicitly using IE 11.
Could somebody help me out here.

Comment: As per their documentation, they had mentioned that they had tested the WSO2 API Manager with IE 11. So it should work with IE 11. You can check whether your client is getting any error or warning message or not. It can give some idea about the issue. You can also consult WSO2 API support. they can also help to narrow down the issue. Ref: https://docs.wso2.com/display/compatibility/Tested+Web+Browsers

Comment: Yes you are absolutely true that as per their documentation it suppose to work with IE 11.But unfortunately it is not working and at the same time no error is popping up.
Instead showing model(sample payload) it is showing empty.

Comment: As WSO2 is not a Microsoft product. We are not able to make any guess about the issue with out any error or warning message. I suggest you to consult a WSO2 API support. They can give any idea about the issue. you can also try to make a test on any other machine with IE 11 to check whether this issue can be produce on any machine or it is a machine specific issue.

Comment: Thank you Deepak. It is not machine specific as we tried multiple machines.

Comment: Unfortunately we do not have any subscription with WSO2 , still do we get wso2 support ?

Comment: I am not sure whether WSO2 provide any free support or not. You can try to check this link may give you some information. https://wso2.com/subscription/

Comment: sure.Appreciate your quick response thank you.

Comment: You can always contact WSO2 by sending an email to dev@wso2.org mailing list regarding your issue since you do not have WSO2 subscription.